# "Python Script For Displaying The Windows Update History"

Tags: python, pywin32, burp

Hello i am attempting to make a  "Python Script For Displaying The Windows Update History".I am new to python and cant find much information on the pywin32 module.If anyone one has some information or examples of this it would be very appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work about it? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  to improve your question

Comment: Currently im looking for examples. I havnt been able to find any information on someone trying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The following script is working for me on Windows 10 (need to run `pip install -U pywinauto` first):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pywinauto import Application

Application().start('control.exe')
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='explorer.exe', title='Control Panel')

app.window(title='Control Panel').ProgramsHyperlink.invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)

app.window(title='Programs').child_window(title='View installed updates', control_type='Hyperlink').invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)

list_box = app.InstalledUpdates.FolderViewListBox

items = list_box.descendants(control_type='ListItem')
all_updates = [item.window_text() for item in items]
print('\nAll updates ({}):\n'.format(len(all_updates)))
print(all_updates)

windows_items = list_box.child_window(title_re='^Microsoft Windows.*', control_type='Group').descendants(control_type='ListItem')
windows_updates = [item.window_text() for item in windows_items]
print('\nWindows updates only ({}):\n'.format(len(windows_updates)))
print(windows_updates)
```

P.S. It's impossible to write such a script using pyWin32 only. `pywinauto` uses `comtypes` package as a dependency for MS UI Automation technology usage (it's mentioned as `backend='uia'` in the script).

P.P.S. Wrote the script from scratch in just an hour (but I'm pywinauto maintainer :) ).